# Is that proof of optimism correct?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy, proof, sat

I have got the following problem given: There are given n Files with length z1,...zn and a usage u1,....un where the sum of all u1,...un equals 1. 0 < u_i < 1

They want to have a sorting where the Time taken to take a file from store is minimal. Example, if z1 = 12, l2 = 3 and u1 = 0,9 and u2 = 0,1 where file 1 is taken first, the approximate time to access is 12* 0,8 + 15* 0,1

My task: Prove that this (greedy) algorithm is optimal.

My Question: Is my answer to that question correct or what should I improve?

My answer:

Suppose the Algorithm is not optimal, there has to exist an order that if more efficennt. For that there have to be two factors being mentioned. The usage and the length. The more a file is used, the shorter its time to access has to be. For that the length of files in the first places before has to be as short as possible. If the formula z1/u1 is being sorted descending. The files with a high usage will be placed lastly. Hence the accesstime is made by all lengths before * usage it means that more often files will be accessed slowly. It is a contradiction to the efficency. Suppose the formula z_i / u_i is unefficient. The division by u_i has the consequence that if more usage is given, the term will be smaller. Which means more often used terms will be accessed faster, hence u_i is < 1 and > 0. If differing from that division, terms with higher usage wont be preferred then, which would be a contradiciton to the efficiency. Also because of z_i at the top of fraction lower lengths will be preferred first. Differing from that, it would mean that terms with longer length should be preferred also. Taking longer terms first is a contradiction to efficiency. Hence all other alternatives of taking another sorting could be contradicted it can be proved that the term is optimal and correct.

Comment: The problem statement is very unclear. You have length z1...zn and usages u1..un, with sum(u_i) = 1. So far it's clear. Now you talk about the "Time taken to take a file from store". Exactly what is the thing being optimized (in terms of a mathematical expression of z's and u's)? Is it to find a permutation of the z_i so that sum(sum(z_i, i<=j) * u_j, 1<=j<=n) is minimized? Note your simple example includes 0.8 which I guess is a typo?

Comment: Your example is a little unclear to me. What is l2 = 3? Should the calculation be 12* 0,9 rather than 12* 0,8? I am guessing l2 = 3 should be z2 = 3 and the 15 comes from cumulatively summing all the z's (so 12+3 in this case)? I tend to doubt the greedy approach is optimal; consider u1=49%, u2=51%, z1=1 and z2=100. If the greedy approach puts file 2 first (because it is accessed more often) then the average time becomes ~100. However, putting file 1 first despite being accessed less would give a time more like ~50. Maybe your greedy algorithm sorts differently?

Comment: The problem-statement is described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optimal-storage-tapes/ , What I want to do now is to proof that the problem is correct.

Comment: eh yeah; 0,8 is a typo actually 0,9 is meant